Can I disable image in xaml?
How can I disable image if I can do it?
For example, [Build your first app link](https://i.sstatic.net/yUV9l.png)
MainPage.xaml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="AppMaui.MainPage">

    <ScrollView>
        <VerticalStackLayout
            Padding="30,0"
            Spacing="25">
            <Image
                Source="dotnet_bot.png"
                HeightRequest="185"
                Aspect="AspectFit"
                SemanticProperties.Description="dot net bot in a race car number eight" />

            <Label
                Text="Hello, World!"
                Style="{StaticResource Headline}"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level1" />

            <Label
                Text="Welcome to &#10;.NET Multi-platform App UI"
                Style="{StaticResource SubHeadline}"
                SemanticProperties.HeadingLevel="Level2"
                SemanticProperties.Description="Welcome to dot net Multi platform App U I" />

            <Button
                x:Name="CounterBtn"
                Text="Click me" 
                SemanticProperties.Hint="Counts the number of times you click"
                Clicked="OnCounterClicked"
                IsEnabled="False"
                HorizontalOptions="Fill" />
        </VerticalStackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</ContentPage>

MainPage.xaml.cs
namespace AppMaui
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        int count = 0;

        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void OnCounterClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            count++;

            if (count == 1)
                CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} time";
            else
                CounterBtn.Text = $"Clicked {count} times";

            SemanticScreenReader.Announce(CounterBtn.Text);
        }
    }

}

I want to disable image for default and make it enabled after clicking button.
I change image, add button
<Button
    x:Name="MakePictureButton"
    Text="Make counter" 
    SemanticProperties.Hint="button make picture of counter"
    Clicked="OnMakePictureClicked"
    HorizontalOptions="Fill" />

and write OnMakePictureClicked
private void OnMakePictureClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (count == 0)
    {
        CounterImage.IsEnabled = true;
        CounterBtn.IsEnabled = true;
        MakePictureButton.IsEnabled = false;
    }
}

but I still can see image before and after clicking any button.
I'm beginer in maui/c#/xaml.
What I need to do?
Can I do this by other way?

If you want to make the image disappear you can do this.
CounterImage.IsVisible = false;

